# associativity of => and chainability of =

Tags: z3

Leonardo: According to http://goedel.cs.uiowa.edu/smtlib/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.0-r10.12.21.pdf, section 3.7.1, `=>` is right associative and `=` is chainable. However, it looks like the online version of Z3 does not support such uses. Is there an option I need to set to get this behavior?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Z3 3.1 (and older versions) do not support these two 'features'.
I will add them to Z3 3.2.

Comment: Z3 3.2 has been released. It fixes the problem.

Comment: The online version still does not support chainable comparisons (< > <= >=) as mentioned in the Ints theory. http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories/Ints.smt2
Are there plans to support those?

Comment: That is correct. They are not supported yet. I will add them soon.